# Live Playback of PCM (wave) Audio from Network Stream

Tags: c#, streaming, wav, networkstream

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858457/how-to-create-a-wave-stream-out-of-raw-audio-samples-in-c), I have I networked micro-controller which collects PCM audio (8-bit, 8 kHz) and streams the data as raw bytes over a TCP network socket. I am able to connect to the device, open a `NetworkStream`, and create a RIFF / wave file out of the collected data.

I would like to take it a step further, and enable live playback of the measurements. My approach so far has been to buffer the incoming data into multiple `MemoryStream`'s with an appropriate RIFF header, and when each chunk is complete to use `System.Media.SoundPlayer` to play the wave file segment. To avoid high latency, each segment is only 0.5 seconds long.

My major issue with this approach is that often there is a distinctive popping sound between segments (since each chunk is not necessarily zero-centered or zero-ended).

**Questions:**

Is there a more suitable or direct method to playback live streaming PCM audio in C#?

If not, are there additional steps I can take to make the multiple playbacks run more smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

I don;t think you can manage it without popping sounds with the SoundPlayer, because there shouldn't be any delay in pushing the buffers. Normally you should always have one extra buffer buffered. But the SoundPlayer only buffers one buffer. Even when the soundplayer gives an event that it is ready, you're already too late to play a new sound.

I advise you to check this link: *Recording and Playing Sound with the Waveform Audio Interface* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446573.aspx
There are some examples of the SoundPlayer (skip those), but also how to use the WaveOut. Look at the section `Playing with WaveOut`.

The SoundPlayer is normally used for notification sounds.